# Personalize Lenovo P2 LED notification

Tags: notification-led, lenovo-p2

I'm new to the Android community and I've just got my new Lenovo P2. I'm really happy with it but there is one thing that bothers me. 
I cant personalize the LED notification settings. For example WhatsApp has no access to the LED control. 
I've tried many apps like light manager and others but without success.

I've seen other P2 phones where the LED control worked properly, so I guess it should work somehow.
Has anyone an idea how I can fix this problem? Possibly without root.